# Book about a kid with powers who's sent to a place where there are other kids with similar abilities

Tags: story-identification, novel

There was a kid and I remember one scene in the beginning of the book. The kid's dad had lost his glasses and they were on the couch underneath something (a newspaper maybe). The kid saw what was underneath and found the glasses without moving the thing on top. I don’t remember what the dad did after that and I think I remember the dad was a scientist or a government worker of some kind, but I’m not positive on that. Somehow the kid got sent to a place with other kids with similar abilities.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, was the kid male or female and do you recall anything about any other characters, or anything else about the plot?

Comment: That scene rings a bell. Was it a comic, by any chance?